# Is there a way to visually display a unit's range?

Tags: starcraft-2

Is there a way to show any unit's range visually?

When you siege the `Siege Tank`, the range-circle will be shown, like [here](http://guidesmedia.ign.com/guides/850126/images/590/starcraft2_b09_067.jpg). Is it possible to show similar circle for `Spine Crawler`, `Roach`, etc.? I want this especially for the `Spine Crawler`, to be able to position it precisely to break the pylon-cannon ramp prison.

Comment: This would be a good use of a custom mod if anyone wants to build it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the original starcraft there was no way to tell short of memorizing.

In starcraft 2 blizzard added this for a couple of units

- Siege tanks in siege mode
- spine/spore crawlers while being placed
- point defense drones
- missle turrets
- photon cannons

While roaches are still a no go, you can use crawlers to break such a siege. Just remember they have the same range as photon cannons

Comment: I to also point out although they have the same range, cannons on the ramp have a greater FOV

Comment: @elp a problem fixed by a single overlord

Comment: And sensor towers

Comment: @Blue sensor towers don't have attack range, in that context the circle means something different

Answer (score 1):

No, but you could try to determine the range (perhaps with the editor) and memorize it.

Precise placement (unless it's used to wall/block) is not that important...